# Running out of GPU memory with PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I am running my own custom deep belief network code using PyTorch and using the LBFGS optimizer. After optimization starts, my GPU starts to run out of memory, fully running out after a couple of batches, but I'm not sure why. Should I be purging memory after each batch is run through the optimizer? My code is as follows (with the portion of code that causes the problem marked):

```
def fine_tuning(self, data, labels, num_epochs=10, max_iter=3):
        '''
        Parameters
        ----------
        data : TYPE torch.Tensor
            N x D tensor with N = num samples, D = num dimensions
        labels : TYPE torch.Tensor
            N x 1 vector of labels for each sample
        num_epochs : TYPE, optional
            DESCRIPTION. The default is 10.
        max_iter : TYPE, optional
            DESCRIPTION. The default is 3.

        Returns
        -------
        None.

        '''
        N = data.shape[0]
        #need to unroll the weights into a typical autoencoder structure
        #encode - code - decode
        for ii in range(len(self.rbm_layers)-1, -1, -1):
            self.rbm_layers.append(self.rbm_layers[ii])
        
        L = len(self.rbm_layers)
        optimizer = torch.optim.LBFGS(params=list(itertools.chain(*[list(self.rbm_layers[ii].parameters()) 
                                                                    for ii in range(L)]
                                                                  )),
                                      max_iter=max_iter,
                                      line_search_fn='strong_wolfe') 
        
        dataset     = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(data, labels)
        dataloader  = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=self.batch_size*10, shuffle=True)
        #fine tune weights for num_epochs
        for epoch in range(1,num_epochs+1):
            with torch.no_grad():
                #get squared error before optimization
                v = self.pass_through_full(data)
                err = (1/N) * torch.sum(torch.pow(data-v.to("cpu"), 2))
            print("\nBefore epoch {}, train squared error: {:.4f}\n".format(epoch, err))
        
           #*******THIS IS THE PROBLEM SECTION*******#
            for ii,(batch,_) in tqdm(enumerate(dataloader), ascii=True, desc="DBN fine-tuning", file=sys.stdout):
                print("Fine-tuning epoch {}, batch {}".format(epoch, ii))
                with torch.no_grad():
                    batch = batch.view(len(batch) , self.rbm_layers[0].visible_units)
                    if self.use_gpu: #are we using a GPU?
                        batch = batch.to(self.device) #if so, send batch to GPU
                    B = batch.shape[0]
                    def closure():
                        optimizer.zero_grad()
                        output = self.pass_through_full(batch)
                        loss = nn.BCELoss(reduction='sum')(output, batch)/B
                        print("Batch {}, loss: {}\r".format(ii, loss))
                        loss.backward()
                        return loss
                    optimizer.step(closure)
```

The error I get is:

```
DBN fine-tuning: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]Fine-tuning epoch 1, batch 0     
Batch 0, loss: 4021.35400390625  
Batch 0, loss: 4017.994873046875  
DBN fine-tuning: 0it [00:00, ?it/s] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   
  File "/home/deep_autoencoder/deep_autoencoder.py", line 260, in fine_tuning  
    optimizer.step(closure)  
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/autograd
/grad_mode.py", line 15, in decorate_context 
    return func(*args, **kwargs)  
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/optim/lb
fgs.py", line 425, in step  
    loss, flat_grad, t, ls_func_evals = _strong_wolfe( 
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/optim/lb
fgs.py", line 96, in _strong_wolfe 
    g_prev = g_new.clone(memory_format=torch.contiguous_format) 
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1.57 GiB (GPU 0; 24.00 GiB total capac
ity; 13.24 GiB already allocated; 1.41 GiB free; 20.07 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

This also racks up memory if I use CPU, so I'm not sure what the solution is here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official document on LBFGS says:

> This is a very memory intensive optimizer (it requires additional `param_bytes * (history_size + 1) bytes`). If it doesn’t fit in memory try reducing the history size, or use a different algorithm.

Since I see you didn't specify the `history_size` parameter in the initialization call of `torch.optim.LBFGS`, it should be 100 by default. Since you have used more than 10GB memory for the first two batches, I guess you need at least hundreds of GB of memory.

I'd suggest setting `history_size` to `1` to confirm that the problem is indeed caused by saving too much history. If it is, try solving it by reducing the history size or the parameter size.